# How to get the selected option only even though the drop-down select has the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple selects and their number depends on the data coming form database, because I want to submit the data using ajax,  so all of them have the same class name, how can I get only the selected value from the user, so the user will select one option each time.

```
<form  method="post" id="group_employee_form">
           <p>Select Country  
           <select name="country" class="country">  
                <option value="">Select Country</option>  
                <option value="1">test1</option>  
                <option value="2">test12</option>  

           </select></p>  
           <p>Select State  
           <select name="state" class="state">  
                <option value="">Select State</option> 
                <option value="1">test1</option>  
                <option value="2">test12</option>   
           </select></p>  

           <p>Select Country  
           <select name="country" class="country">  
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                <option value="1">test1</option>  
                <option value="2">test12</option>               

           </select></p>  
           <p>Select State  
           <select name="state" class="state">  
                <option value="">Select State</option>  
                <option value="1">test1</option>  
                <option value="2">test12</option>   
           </select></p>  

           <input type="submit">
           </form>
```

This's the JQuery code

```
 <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  


                $(document).on('submit','form#group_employee_form',function(e){
                          e.preventDefault();
                              var group_id = $(".state").val();

                            alert(group_id);
                });
     });  
     </script>
```

The Jquery code returns value from the first  select only.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
// this for selected text by value    

$('#mySelect').val('ab').change();
 //or
$('#mySelect').val('ab').trigger("change");

// this for get slelected options values

$('#mySelect > option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Thank you, but both solutions return an object not a value!

Comment: you want return value from selected option ? or selected option by value

Comment: I want the value so I can insert it into the database. I'm sending the value by using ajax and then  inserting it.

Comment: Thank you, but it's the same as this one, it return the value of first select only. if I selected an option from the second select it return empty value.  notice that the 2 of the selects  have the same class!